# How to knit a button loop?

Tags: knitting

If knitting an item which needs a button to secure something - like a button on the back of a pair of glittens, (a fingerless glove with a retractable mitten) how would you knit this into a row? Assume, say a 27 st per row, and the loop would be in the absolute middle so st 14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1: yarn over (small circle)**

A yarn over generally works well. Do remember to reduce afterwards, so your stitch count stays the same. In your example that would be:

> k13, yo, k2tog, k12

Knit the next row normally. Treat the yarn over as if it was a normal stitch.

**Option 2: double yarn over (larger circle)**

If you want a bigger buttonhole, it is possible to use a double yarn over. Remember to decrease on both sides in this case, so your stitch count remains the same. Use ssk for a left leaning decrease and k2tog for a right leaning one.

> k12, ssk, yo, yo, k2tog, k11

Knit the next row normally, except the two yarn overs. You have two options for handling this one:

1. You can knit one and purl the other.
2. You can slip the first yarn over off the needle, so you only have one left. Then you knit that stitch [through both the front and the back](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/knit-in-the-front-and-back-2116509).

**Option 3: bind off and cast on (long)**

Alternatively, you can make a long buttonhole. The top two options are a bit easier and are generally sufficient, but it's good to know a long buttonhole is possible too.

With the right side of your work facing you, you bind off a couple stitches. On the next row you cast them on again. For example (assuming flat stockinette):

> Row 1 (right side): k10, bind off 7, k10
>
> Row 2 (wrong side): p10, cast on 7, p10

You can use your favourite method to cast on the stitches on row 2 that works in the middle of a row, for example one of [these](https://www.susannawinter.net/single-post/2018/10/26/5-Ways-to-Cast-on-in-the-Middle-of-a-Row-Tutorial).

<sup><sub>I am not affiliated with either of the linked blogs. I simply believe they offer good explanation of the techniques. If they exist, or exist in the future, feel free to replace them with links to questions on this network instead.</sub></sup>